# Reading GPG passphrase from the physical keyboard in OpenBSD

Tags: keyboard, openbsd, gpg, gpg-agent, synergy

I'm using [Synergy](http://synergy-project.org/) to control an OpenBSD desktop from a Linux computer (think of it like a VNC client/server). That is to say what I type on the keyboard goes through a network connection before it reaches the remote terminal.

How do I make sure that gpg-agent reads a passphrase only when it's typed from the **physical** keyboard connected to the OpenBSD workstation? In other words, how do I make sure that `stdin` comes from the keyboard and **not** from synergy?

I'm working on a worst-case scenario where the linux box I'm using to control the remote OpenBSD machine is compromised with a keylogger. Note that synergy works in a reversed client-server configuration, i.e. the OpenBSD machine is the synergy *client*, and the Linux box is the synergy *server*.

I've tried exporting `GPG_TTY` to `/dev/wskbd0` but to no avail. Is that even possible?

Comment: When logged in at the OpenBSD console, the tty device will be `/dev/ttyC*` (eg, `/dev/ttyC0` for the first VT). That said, I'm not sure if setting `GPG_TTY` to that device will work, but perhaps give it a try? If it doesn't work, please give us as much detail as possible